# Initialize a list using inline for loop

Tags: python

I am initializing my list object using following code.

```
list = [
    func1(centroids[0],value),
    func1(centroids[1],value),
    ....,
    func1(centroids[n],value)]
```

I am trying to do it a more elegant way using some inline iteration. Following is the pseudo code of one possible way.

```
list = [value for value in func1(centroids[n],value)]
```

I am not clear how to call func1 in an iterative way. Can you suggest a possible implementation?

Comment: `lst = [func1(centroids[i], value) for i in range(n + 1)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a list of objects, Python knows how to iterate over it directly so you can eliminate the index shown in most of the other answers,

```
res = [func1(c, value) for c in centroids]
```

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

A simple **list comprehension** consists of the "template" list element, followed by the iterator needed to step through the desired values.

```
my_list = [func1(centroids[0],value) 
               for n in range(n+1)]
```

Comment: Nope -- several of us groaned at the same time, I see.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
list = [func1(centroids[x], value) for x in range(n)]
```

This is called a list comprehension. Put the values that you want the list to contain up front, then followed by the for loop. You can use the iterating variable of the for loop with the value. In this code, you set up `n` number(s) of variable(s) from the function call `func1(centroids[x], value)`. If the variable `n` equals to, let's say, 4, `list = [func1(centroids[0], value), func1(centroids[0], value), func1(centroids[0], value), func1(centroids[0], value)]` would be equal to the code above

Comment: You're calling it `list`?

Comment: alternatively `[func1(c, value) for c in centroids]`

Comment: and again alternatively `map(lambda centroid: func(centroid, value), centroids)`

Comment: @user2699 You can add this as the solutions please